# Civimail does not save settings

Tags: civimail, settings

I'm trying to save new settings in civicrm/admin/mail form. 
I click "save" and get the "Your changes have been saved" message but, when refreshing the page, the form is empty as it was before.

We're stuck at the 4.2.9 civicrm version, as our provider does not provide the php features new versions require

Please help, we need to change these settings in order to be compliant to our provider's smtp policy.

We are eventually able to change settings in db tables, if somebody could tell us where to find them (there are really a lot of tables to search from)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is separate, I know, but if you're on a version that's that old, there are a bunch of security vulnerabilities that have been fixed since then (see https://civicrm.org/advisory), not to mention things fixed in newer PHP versions.

Unless your hosting provider is planning on providing what you need in the near future, you really should plan on moving to a new host sometime soon.

Comment: You're definetely right, but it could be not easy. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

the table is most likely: civicrm_mail_settings

It depends on what specific field you want to change, but most of the fields in that form are from the above table

Comment: I came across civicrm_mail_settings, but it has only 2 rows: mailboxes configuration (pop3 server, password), I don't kno how to add settings like "Mailer Throttle Time".
Thanks anyway :-)

Thanks a lot,
Stefano

Comment: They are probably stored in the config object and serialized in the db

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 4.2.9 you could at least upgrade to the latest in that series, which is [4.2.20](https://sourceforge.net/projects/civicrm/files/civicrm-stable/4.2.20/). This may solve your problem.